# How to create one collection by combining data from two collections?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am having a go at my first Database attempt with SQL. I want the Database to hold a table of User. Each User has attributes as UserName, FirstName, LastName, etc. but also has a Role. The Role is connected with a foreign key in the User table.

```
List<User>users = new List<User>()
users.add(UserId = 1, UserName = "John" UserRoleId=1);
users.add(UserId = 2, UserName = "Luke" UserRoleId=2);
users.add(UserId = 3, UserName = "Marc" UserRoleId=3);
users.add(UserId = 4, UserName = "Mathew" UserRoleId=3);

List<UserRole>userRoles = new <UserRole>userRoles();
userRoles.add(UserRoleId = 1 , UserRole = "Admin");
userRoles.add(UserRoleId = 2 , UserRole = "Project Manager");
userRoles.add(UserRoleId = 3 , UserRole = "Planner");
```

I want to create a new list of Objects named displayUser which hold the UserRole.
so the result should look something like.

```
UserId=1, UserName = "John", UserRole = "Admin"
UserId=2, UserName = "Luke", UserRole = "Project Manager"
UserId=3, UserName = "Marc", UserRole = "Planner"
UserId=4, UserName = "Mathew", UserRole = "Planner"
```

So the general Question is: How do I easily create one collection combining data from two collections?

Answer (score 1):

You `join` the tables and create a projection from the two tables.

```
var q = from u in users
        join r in userRoles on u.UserRoleId equals r.UserRoleId 
        select new { u.UserId, u.UserName, r.UserRole };
```

If a user has many roles and you want a collection of the roles per user you can use a `GroupJoin`

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ with a join like that:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

users.Add(new User { UserId = 1, UserName = "John", UserRoleId = 1 });
users.Add(new User { UserId = 2, UserName = "Luke", UserRoleId = 2 });
users.Add(new User { UserId = 3, UserName = "Marc", UserRoleId = 3 });
users.Add(new User { UserId = 4, UserName = "Mathew", UserRoleId = 3 });

List<UserRole> userRoles = new List<UserRole>();

userRoles.Add(new UserRole { UserRoleId = 1, UserRoleName = "Admin" });
userRoles.Add(new UserRole { UserRoleId = 2, UserRoleName = "Project Manager" });
userRoles.Add(new UserRole { UserRoleId = 3, UserRoleName = "Planner" });

var result = from user in users
             join userRole in userRoles on user.UserRoleId equals userRole.UserRoleId
             select new
             {
               user.UserId,
               user.UserName,
               userRole.UserRoleName
             };

foreach ( var item in result )
  Console.WriteLine($"{item.UserId}, {item.UserName}, {item.UserRoleName}");
```

It selects items from the two lists joined by the role id and creates new named and typed items as desired.

The result query can be transformed into a `List<(int, string, string)>` with:

```
var list = result.ToList();
```

*Output*

```
1, John, Admin
2, Luke, Project Manager
3, Marc, Planner
4, Mathew, Planner
```